# Type of normalization

Tags: terminology, normalization

Suppose you have some vector $[a_1, \ldots, a_n]$ where the terms are non-negative.

How do you call the normalization method where you divide each element by the sum (to get a probability vector)? i.e. $$a_i \mapsto \frac{a_i}{\sum a_j}$$

Comment: This is not necessarily a probability vector -- are the $a_i$ constrained to be positive?

Comment: @Sycorax, yes, sorry for not mentioning that

Answer (score 1):

You could call $a_i \mapsto \dfrac{a_i}{\sum\limits_j |a_j|}$ a Manhattan or $\ell_1$*-norm*alisation, effectively projecting each point onto the boundary of a unit hyperoctahedron or [cross-polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope), in rather the same way that  $a_i \mapsto \dfrac{a_i}{\sqrt{\sum\limits_j a_j^2}}$ could be called  a Euclidean or $\ell_2$*-norm*alisation projecting each point onto  the boundary of a unit hypersphere.

As you say, if the $a_i$ are all non-negative and at least one is positive, then this is equivalent to $a_i \mapsto \dfrac{a_i}{\sum\limits_j a_j}$ and once normalised they add up to $1$ (you are effectively restricting yourself to a single orthant simplex facet of the unit hyperoctahedron) so these could represent a probability distribution. In a sense you could be starting with values proportional to the probabilities, and the normalisation turns them into actual probabilities.